Angular 17 meta tag value not update while sharing url on social media platform
enter image description here
Here in html elements tags are updated but while sharing that will pick static added tag on html file.

        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: this.advertisementDetail.name });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: this.advertisementDetail.description });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: this.advertisementDetail.tumbnail });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: window.location.href });

I want like what tag value i have updated that need to visible while sharing on social media platform

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
